# Page jumps to top when using Javascript rotating background

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript for a rotating background image. The problem is, every time the image changes, the page jumps to the top. Hopefully this is an easy fix!

Here is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(window).load(function(){


var initialBg =  $('#slider').css("background-image"); // added

var firstTime = true;
var arr = [initialBg, "url(/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/slider2-explore.png)", "url(/wp-    content/uploads/2013/03/slider3-experience.png)"];
(function recurse(counter) {
    var bgImage = arr[counter];
    if (firstTime == false) {
        $("#slider").fadeOut("slow", function(){
            $('#slider').css('background-image', bgImage);
        });
        $("#slider").fadeIn("slow");
    } else {
        firstTime = false;
    }               
    delete arr[counter];
    arr.push(bgImage);
    setTimeout(function() {
        recurse(counter + 1);
    }, 4500);  
})(0);  

});
</script>
```

Comment: The only thing that appears suspect to me is 'arr.push(bgImage);'. It may be acting as an in-page anchor.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: I can't be sure of anything without a demo. I'm not quite a JS wizard. :-)

Comment: I am certainly not either:) I'm not sure what you mean about a demo? Here is a link to the page: http://awaybug.com

Comment: Probably unrelated: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://awaybug.com/images/pagebackground.jpg"

Comment: Also unrelated: You can get rid of your horizontal scrolling by putting {margin: 0} on body and removing negative side margins from #slider, .footerbackground, and the div following .footerbackground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page jumps because for an instant #slider is absent and the other page content collapses into its space. Try this:

```
#slider_wrapper {
    height: 550px;
}

<div id="slider_wrapper">
    <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

You may also want to preload your background images to prevent odd fadeIn delays.

Comment: Fantastic, that did the trick! I had tried defining the height for the #slider div, but that didn't work. Do you mind telling me the best way to preload the images?

Comment: You can either put them in offscreen HTML, say with styles like {position: absolute; left: -999em;}, or you can use a JS preloader. Google that or search SO. 

Please accept and/or upvote any helpful answers on SO.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a huge help. I hope you don't mind if I ask one more question- any ideas why the top portion of the text box that overlays my rotating background looks like it's jumping from behind to in front of the background every time it changes?

Comment: I saw that, too. I don't know enough about jQuery innards to explain it. I tried z-index as a remedy and had no luck. I'll take another look.

Comment: Thanks, I tried zindex too. I just adjusted my fade in/out times, and it looks like the text box is behind while the fades are happening, then jumps in front while the background is stationary. Don't know if that helps?

Comment: Try this: .center {position: relative;} And don't forget the things I mentioned above for your horizontal scroll. Sidescroll is ugly! :-) Very nice site, by the way.